# Twitter web application to show tweets mentioning me

Tags: twitter

Recently under some youtube videos there have been a Twitter feed, showing all tweets relevant to the video and what people are saying about it.

I was wondering how I could implement it on my website, except showing tweets relevant to my company's name.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a very general question so I'm providing you with a general answer. Use the Twitter API to pull data that is marked with @YourCompanyName or #YourCompany.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

Pretty straight forward.